# WordPress permalinks issue on online server

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, permalinks

I work first on localhost (xampp) and I completed the work of WordPress. It runs successfully, but when I upload all my project on online server the permalinks not work properly.

I first save permalinks "Default" and check the website, the website run successfully, but when change it to "Post Name" it shows me 404 error.

What the issue is:

- is my hosting server not good?
- or the issue comes from Wordpress theme?

Comment: is mod_rewrite "ON" on your server ? OR .htaccess file is writable ?

Comment: how can i check this on a server

Comment: you can ask in support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

1. Check if `mod_rewrite` module loaded. You can ask support or create new file in root folder, for example `phpinfo.php` add this script `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` so you can access it via `http://yourwebsite.com/phpinfo.php`

   Check the `mod_rewrite` status on `Loaded Modules` row.
2. Make sure htaccess is writeable
3. Goto Wordpress Admin -> Setting -> Permalink. On Common Settings Section,make sure it's not set to 'default'. Try to select other option and save changes. If wordpress can't write the files, It will show notification and htaccess script. Copy that script manually to your .htaccess file

I hope this Help. If you still get challange feel free to ask

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

first of all Remove your `.htaccess` file from the wordpress root directory and change the permalink setting.